# Users get logged out every 10 to 20 minutes (claims authentication)

Tags: authorization, single-sign-on, claims-based-identity

For some reason users get redirected back to login.microsoftonline.com almost every 10/20 minutes. This is quite annoying, since the code below is used to login users for a CMS.

Could anyone tell me whats wrong with the following code and why our users get logged out/redirected back to login.microsoftonline.com? Session lifetime is set to 60 minutes, so it must be something with the authorization itself.

Should we use WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType or DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie?

We want to allow users to sign in using a form (/account/inloggen) or using a button called 'Azure SSO' (which is an external login)

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
  // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
  app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
  app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

  // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
  // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
  // Configure the sign in cookie

  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
  {
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/account/inloggen"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
      OnResponseSignIn = ctx =>
      {
        ctx.Identity = TransformClaims(ctx.Identity);
        ctx.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7.0);
      },
      OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                              validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                              regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    },
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7.0),
    SlidingExpiration = true
  });

  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
  {
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
      OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
          validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
          regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    },
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7.0),
    SlidingExpiration = true
  });

  app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
  {
    MetadataAddress = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/federationmetadata.xml",
    Wtrealm = "https://portal.domain.com",
    Caption = "Azure SSO",
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
    UseTokenLifetime = false,
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive
  });

  app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
}
```

When and why should we use this?

```
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

As you might've noticed im fairly new to all this. I've browsed stack overflow and Googled lots of examples, but there is no clear answer/tutorial which explains different authorization types, their properties and how they are used.

Answer (score 0):

Your validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) is set to 30 minutes.

validateInterval is not the same as expiring cookies on a given time fame.
For example a user logs in at Location A, then goes to location B and signs in and changes the password. Then they come back to Location A after 30 mins. They will be signed out.

The SecurityStampValidator is created anytime a password is created/changed or an **external login is added/removed.**

**Source**: http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity-Cookie-Authentication-Timeouts/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However it's set to 30 minutes and the current user gets logged out every 10-20 minutes, while SlidingExpiration is set to true. How come the users gets logged out even though SlidingExpiration is enabled?

Would the regenerateIdentity function not generate a new valid Identity? I cant think of anything else.